# what this javascript code mean? a pattern to create empty object?

Tags: javascript

How this work in Javascript engine:

```
var oojs = (function(oojs) {

    return oojs;
})(oojs || {})
```

Another question is: what this mean

```
(oojs || {})
```

Comment: Look up IIFE and short-circuit operators.

Comment: It means if !oojs then {}

Comment: @Tsalikidis (oojs || {}), now oojs is = IIFE , this mean passing this IIFE to IIFE?

Comment: Yes, it's passing the oojs variable (or and empty object) as an argument to this IIFE. Using oojs everywhere in this example code, makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: `(oojs || {})` means to use `oojs` if it's not null, otherwise use an empty object.